# downloadButton/ downloadHandler does not recognize filename argument

Tags: r, file, download, shiny, rstudio

I've run into a problem with `downloadHandler()` in Shiny:
If I want to download any file via this function, the filename in the download window is the same as the name of the output-variable (in the example: "downloadData"), but not as it is declared in "filename=" in downloadHandler() (which should be "data-2017-02-13.csv").

Note that the following example is from the downloadHandler() - help page, so I guess there is a general problem with R or RStudio in which I write R scripts.
Additionally when I open the shiny app in a web browser, the problem vanishes.
This partially solves it, but I would still like to know why shiny is behaving differently inside RStudio and a web browser.

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Our dataset
  data <- mtcars

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

and here the download window I get:
[image]

Comment: is it only in the preview or also inside the  browser? try `runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)`

Comment: This is browser dependent.

Comment: I have the same problem. I included a download button into an app and wondered why it would use the name of the output variable. In a browser it works.
Another thing that does not work in shiny in RStudio is to force the content type of the output file via the contentType argument in downloadHandler. You need to open the app in chrome for it to work. Perhaps both differences have a similar reason.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same issue when I used the RStudio preview window and was able to solve this issue by always opening a browser with the command

`runApp(launch.browser = TRUE)`

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was feeling insane (this is like 2 lines of very simple code - not working properly!)